# Alteryx connection to Oracle database

Tags: database, oracle, odbc, alteryx, simba

I am trying to connect to oracle database through Alteryx. I keep getting the same error message as below:

> connection error im003 specified driver could not be found due to
> system error 126: the specified module could not be found. (simba
> oracle odbc driver, c:\program files\simba oracle odbc
> driver\lib\oracleodbc_sb64.dll)

I tried downloading the `Simba Oracle ODBC Driver` which contains the `oracleodbc_sb64.dll` file. However I still get the same error.

[image]

any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Is Alteryx a 64-bit program?

Comment: yes it is Wernfried

Comment: Maybe try [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to find out which files are loaded and where it actually fails.